# Python equivalent for Global (??) help section in R

Tags: python, r

What is python equivalent to R global search (??) which will give result from all packages, I am from R background and find difficulty in Python help/search like I want to check 'nunique' function capability from pandas, I am using below code

```
nunique()?
nunique?
help(nunique)
help(nunique())
pydoc -k nunique()
pydoc -k nunique
```

Nothing is giving result, also how to search when I don't know about module/package.

Comment: You just need to specify the full path so that python knows what function you're talking about
help(pandas.Series.nunique)

Comment: thanks for reply, but for this, I need to know complete hierarchy like Pandas>Series then searched module, do we have anything which can directly search

Comment: if the function is imported then you can just call help on it. Otherwise there is no global hierarchy search that i'm aware of. As an aside, when would you need such a thing?

Comment: actually I am new to python and learning things from online material, so I am not very used to its packages etc. in R, we just need to search using ?? it will list all the packages where such function found ...I was looking that kind of function here, anyway...I will go with hierarchy

Comment: I think there is only help() and dir() (.. to check what's in a module).

Answer (score 0):

I found these are useful commands

```
#  help on build in function 'len'
help(len) 
#  list of all help
dir(len) 
#  help on build in function 'len'
len? 
# a package specific help, here pd is pandas
help(pd.unique)
```